# Origine du mot "brouzouf"

Tags: étymologie, registre-familier

Je suis à la recherche d'une source fiable pour l'origine du mot brouzouf. J'ai vu sur internet de gens qui parlent que ça vient de *[Objectif Nul](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectif_Nul)*. D'autres parlent de *Valérian et Laureline*. Et finalement le wiktionaire dit

> Proviendrait d'un article d'un journal satirique "Le Monstre", vers 1986-1987. Satire du journal Le Monde, dans un des articles était mentionné un pays imaginaire, le Brouzoufland, dont la monnaie, le Brouzouf, connaissait une inflation spectaculaire.

avec aucun lien, donc j'ai du mal à confirmer (surtout que les dates se superposent avec l'*Objectif Nul*). Aussi la version sur le wiktionaire a été rajouté par un utilisateur anonyme.

Il y a-t-il une manière de vérifier les exemplaires de *Le Monstre*? Où d'avoir une confirmation directe de sa création specifiquement pour *Objectif Nul* ou pour Valérian?

Answer (score 1):

Il y avait certainement beaucoup de [brouzoufs dans Objectif Nul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6lqFlQ7EAM&t=223s), ici en 1987.

Il n'y avait pas de brouzoufs dans Valérian (C'était des bloutoks):

[image]

Il n'existe pas de source attestant que *Le Monstre* ait aussi utilisé ce terme.

Comment: Ok. Mais est-qu'il y a une manière de faire une recherche (même à la main) sur des anciens versions de *Le Monstre*? Sinon ça reste un possibilité.

Comment: Une autre possibilité serait d'avoir une confirmation directe que c'était inventé pour Objectif Nul.

Comment: Consulter les numéros du Monstre est à priori possible en se rendant à la BnF après avoir fait une demande et probablement en justifiant le motif de la recherche. Toutes les publications font l'objet d'un dépôt légal. Les 16 numéros du Monstre y sont [référencés](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb34394395m).

Comment: Pour ce qui est des Nuls, contacter Alain Chabat, Chantal Lauby ou Dominique Faruggia peut être tenté...

Answer (score 0):

Sauf erreur le monstre avait été publié par le groupe jalon fondé par Basile de Koch le frère de Karl Zéro qui travaillait alors à Canal plus… Comme les nuls ! Ceci peut expliquer cela.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).